# One-finger-down not working when onKeyDown implemented

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I am just making some tests and I created a simple immersion menu in a hello world activity. To do that, like it is said [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/immersion-menus), I had to implement the method onKeyDown:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
        openOptionsMenu();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The menu is shown properly but the problem is that now the one-finger-down gesture to just close the app doesn't work and for any reason I had to make a two-finger-down gesture to close it. Why is it happening?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe using a gesture detector instead of onKeyDown will work better? https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/touch

Comment: Well, I was just making some simple tests and I just followed the documentation on Google Developer site and it sounds weird for me that adding this I was disabling the basic one-finger-down action. Sure there is other ways to make it better but I just wanted to understand why it was happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you override the onKeyDown function.

You have two solution :

- Handle yourself the KEYCODE_BACK like that :

  if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
              onBackPressed();
              return true;
  }
- return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); instead of return false;

Comment: To make it easier I just tested the second option and everything works as expected. Actually it makes sense once you explained, so very good answer.